# Como transformar procedure em DLL?

Tags: visual-basic-6, dll, procedure

Boa Noite. Sou novo na área de programação, consegui um estágio recentemente apesar de não ter experiência. Por sem experiencia não digo leigo, ter somente noções de POO, Banco de dados, etc.

Esses dias tive a função de fazer procedure para Fazer Inserts e Updates numa base de dados, uma vitória pra mim já que deu tudo certo.

Agora me foi dito que preciso criar uma DLL para tais procedures. Pelo que entendi era pra outra empresa acessar tal procedure, alguém poderia me ajudar ? Andei pesquisando mas como é urgente preciso de ajuda, nem que for um caminho para eu conseguir desenvolver o mais rápido possível.
Fiz as procedures em SQL Server e na empresa Utilizamos VB.

Desde já obrigado, pessoal
Abs

Comment: Ué, você deve criar classes e métodos para que se possa ser instanciado ao referenciar a dll, consequentemente, os métodos são para executar as procedures

Comment: vb.net ou vb6 ?

Comment: Creio que deve ser em VB6. Na realidade eu perguntei por saber o básico somente. Na realidade na minha visão um WebService ja serviria mas não entendi por que ele pediu uma DLL. Não saberia como montar isso, seria somente funções comuns para executa-las e depois converter para DLL ?

Comment: Seria uma class library com as funções ué, com base na sua pergunta é isso, agora se a comunicação pode ser vinda externa, aí você tem que explicar